# Is there a way to export the Log Analytics Query history from Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to capture a historical log of all the queries run against the data stored in Application Insights which is for compliance purposes. You are able to view a history list of the queries ran but I can't see a way to view/access the raw data of this list.

[image: Screenshot]

From my investigation in the settings tab in the Log (Analytics) page it says that this list is saved for 30 days:

> Log Analytics query history is saved for 30 days globally.
>   Query history may be cleared using the “clear history” button.

I have tried searching through the settings and online documentation but no mention of the history of queries ran or where it can be found.

Does anyone know of a way to access this list of historical queries ran?

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting question, but AFAIK, an export of the historical data is not possible, as it seems to be more of a feature on the Azure Portal that is not exposed by any of [Log Analytics](https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Using-the-API) or [Application Insights](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/overview) REST APIs.

Digging this further, I noticed that one of the network calls involves hitting the URL: https://portal.loganalytics.io/. But the push now is towards moving to the Azure Portal, as discussed in [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/22413) issue.

Nevertheless, I will still check with our internal Teams and let you know if I have something more to share.

Hope this helps!